# Как найти non-SDK interface в приложении?

Tags: java, android

Если мы указываем в gradle вот эти две строчки

```
buildToolsVersion "28.0.0" 
targetSdkVersion 28
```

И пытаемся запустить android P , то приложение не работает.
Указывает на non-SDK interface в приложении.

И так вопросы:

1. Как эти интерфейсы найти в приложении?
2. Как эти интерфейсы исправить(ибо как я понимаю они могут быть и в либах)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того,чтобы найти non-sdk interfaces:

1.Нажать на Analyze

2.Выбрать Inspec Code

3.Выбрать модуль и нажать OK

4.Начнется поиск информации по вашему коду

5.Вам будет предоставлен список с предупреждениями, ошибками. Нужно исправить их.

P.S Вы сразу ошибки по увидите non-sdk interfaces
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Для этого существует замечательный [инструмент Lint](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint)

К счастью он автоматом работает в Android Studio.

Надо заглянуть в отчет об ошибках, предупреждениях Lint - по умолчанию он лежит в каталоге:

```
<path-to-project>/app/build/reports/lint-results.html
```

Гарантирую увлекательное чтение - много нового узнаете о качестве своего кода.

Comment: не вижу папку reports

Comment: читайте документацию - ссылка в ответе, там все написано куда смотреть, что тыкать - занимайтесь

Comment: Ответ читайте документацию - это не ответ на вопрос =)
Спасибо, вы сделали stackoverflow своим ответом лучше =)

Comment: @АнтонМартынов я в стеке был когда вы еще под стол пешком ходили, поэтому не учите меня что здесь правильно, а что нет. Во вторых не зная общего контекста среды разработки и его настроек невозможно что-то посоветовать и третье: я всегда даю не конкретные рецепты, а только указываю путь нахождения верного ответа - сознаю не всем это нравится, но тут уж на вкус и цвет...

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться,почему большинство разработчиков, так же как и вы указывают на путь, а не дают конкретный ответ?

Ведь есть конкретный вопрос - есть конкретный ответ.

И я как разработчик, хочу сказать что это большая проблема, вместо того чтобы сократить время получив конкретный ответ, ты тратишь его еще больше на поиск пазлов.

Comment: Можно, рассказываю: 1) потому что способов решения существует много, в вашем конкретном случае я насчитал 6 способов (возможно их еще больше). Причем применение конкретного способа зависит от конфигурации вашего проекта: вы работаете с командной строки, через IDE Android Studio  с gradle или без, через Eclipse или как то еще. 2) указывается именно путь ибо сказано: *дай рыбу накормишь голодного на 1 день, научи ловить рыбу - накормишь на всю жизнь* - я предпочитаю таки научить ловить рыбу